# How to use constant value in Linq left join?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to use constant value in left join as below sql in Linq expression. How to achieve that in linq expression.

```
 SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[s1AlertLog] AS [Extent1]            
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[smManualChapter] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[mwEventDetailKey] = [Extent4].[ID] and [Extent1].mwEventTypeKey = 300  Where Extent1.mwcUsersKey = 8000
```

Linq

```
    var list = (from alert in ctx.Set<S1AlertLog>()
                      join smManualChapter in ctx.Set<SmManualChapter>() on new { alert.MwEventDetailKey, alert.MwEventTypeKey } equals new { smManualChapter.ID, 300}
                          into temp1 
                      from tempChapter in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select  alert
            );

  var result = list.Where(x=>x.mwcUsersKey == 8000);
```

Comment: Your linq query only returns elements of the first set. The sql statement returns a join of both sets. Maybe there's another mistake in the linq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to the same field names in the anonymous types:

```
var list = (from alert in ctx.Set<S1AlertLog>()
              join smManualChapter in ctx.Set<SmManualChapter>() 
                  on new { d = alert.MwEventDetailKey, t = alert.MwEventTypeKey } 
              equals new { d = smManualChapter.ID    , t = 300 }
                  into temp1 
              from tempChapter in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select  alert
        );
```